# Multi/level query in MySQl - is an extra foreign key necessary?

Tags: mysql

Lets say that I have 3 tables:

- departments, each of which has 0..n

  - jobs, each of which has 0..n

    - people

Given a department, how do I get all the people who work in that department?  Can I do it with a single SELECT?

I have set up [a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1f7f1/2/0) with some sample data, but I can't formulate the correct query.

Can it be done with some `JOIN` magic? Or do I need to add a foreign key in the `peeps` table, pointing back to the `department_id`?

Comment: You join people with jobs, and jobs with departments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple join

```
SELECT people.*
FROM departments 
INNER JOIN jobs ON departments.deperatment_id = jobs.deperatment_id
INNER JOIN people ON jobs.job_id = people.job_id
WHERE departments.deperatment_id = 1
```

You will need to amend the column names in the join conditions to the ones used in your tables.

Note that your sample tables on SQL fiddle do not have any indexes. Adding these is VERY important for performance.

Comment: Btw, would you implement it with that query, or an extra FK? The extra FK would need to be updated if a person changed department, bu no doubt execution time would be much quicker with a simple `SELECT * FROM peeps WHERE peeps.department_id = X`  It probably depends on how many rows the table has, I guess.

Comment: A foreign key is really just an index related to another table. What you are suggesting is to duplicate data which inevitably will get out of sync at some point. With a simple query like that with good indexes the performance should be very good.